# What's the most effective way to make Nut Shots?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

In the Saintsbook, there's a challenge from Shaundi to make 25 Nut Shots. However, I'm having difficulty pulling this off (I also had a hard time completing this challenge in Saints Row 2 and was never able to get 3 gold stars).

I'm currently dual-wielding 45 Shepherds to make my attempts. I was previously using a shotgun, but it seemed to be just killing the guys before I received credit for the Nut Shot. Sometimes I see them grabbing at their groin in pain, but I still don't get credit.

How can I effectively complete this challenge? Does this have to be a killing blow? Does it have to *not* be a killing blow? Is there any particular weapon that is better for this challenge?

Comment: I picked up a bunch of random Nut Shots when I was firing up at enemies on a catwalk. Perhaps you could find a spot that places you below an endless stream of gang members for a better attack angle.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I did some more research on this last night:

- I only seem to be able to do this on male gang members and STAG footsoldiers.  I haven't yet gotten a nutshot on a female gang member or any police officer.  I don't know that it is impossible, but it's at least much harder.
- Try to shoot at them when they're facing you.  If they turn to the side it becomes next to impossible to get a nut shot.
- Aim for the belt buckle, if they have one.  If not, the waist of their pants.  If you aim any lower, it tends to count as a leg shot and they'll turn sideways instead of grabbing themselves.  (This game apparently takes some liberties with anatomy...)
- You have to kill with the nut shot to get credit. It doesn't have to be a one-shot kill, but the killing shot must be dealt in the testicular area.

I believe the upgraded pistols work best, just because of accuracy.  I also had pretty good luck with the laser assault rifle.  It's still very inexact, I'll probably get nut shots on 20% of the people I'm trying to get it on.

Since you've got to do a lot of careful aiming, taking a human shield first also helps.

Comment: I'm fairly sure I got a nut shot from hitting a female character in the groin.

Comment: @agent86 The article is about SR2, are we sure the functionality is the same in SR3?

Comment: Hmm, I had thought that was for SR3, but you're right.  I'll double check tonight with my copy of SR3, and in the meantime see if I can find some better sources.

Comment: So do I actually have to kill them to get credit for the nutshot or not? I find it difficult to tell in the hecticness of full firefights. :/

Comment: I don't think you can get a nut shot on a cop: I saw the nut-shot animation tonight after shooting one and did not get credit for it. It doesn't have to be a one-shot kill, though, just the last shot. I've also had the most success with pistols: I just kneel and aim at the belt.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I've done some experimenting with the information here. Below are my tips and strategies to achieve Nut Shot kills toward the Challenge. This information pertains entirely to Saints Row The Third, or Saints Row 3.

- The actual area required for a Nut Shot is not the groin, but more the navel area, or 'belt buckle' perhaps.
- The killing blow must be a 'Nut Shot' for the count to rise.
- The fully upgraded 45 SHEPARD is probably easiest to achieve this with.
- As far as I can tell, you can't 'Nut Shot' females on Saints Row 3. (I know you could on the second.)
- The MORNINGSTAR Syndicate members are ideal targets. Their male members all wear RED shirts and BLACK pants. Fire at the area where these two colours meet (Where the shirt tucks into the pants) for /easier/ nut shots.

Hope this helps!

Edit: I'd just like to add - about 30 seconds after posting this guide I returned to playing and scored a DOUBLE nut shot on two lined up goons! 45 SHEPARD, aim at the exact meeting point of the shirt/pants, instant results (I promise!) :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Nutshots only count on threats (not civilians)
2. You can pull off "Nutshots" on females.

The easiest method I've found for getting nutshots is to find a large number of gang members in a small space, line up your sights on one of their groin areas then strafe left to right, not touching your right thumbstick, and just freefire with a pistol.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the hardest time with this until I realized that the Mascots are super easy to nutshot.

Just go to one of Professor Genki's SERC, and repeat until you get 25. **Hot Dog** is easiest to get...